# Add a table to sqlite database

Tags: python, sqlite, peewee

I have a sqlite database with already existing tables

```
db = SqliteDatabase("C:/database.db")


class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = db

class SymbolModel(BaseModel):
    symbol = CharField()

class EquityModel(BaseModel):
    symbol = ForeignKeyField(SymbolModel, backref='equity')
```

This works fine.

Now I'd like to add a table, so I've modified my models.py like this:

```
class EarningsReleaseModel(BaseModel):
    symbol = ForeignKeyField(SymbolModel, backref='earningsrelease')
```

and called, from a shell:

```
db.create_tables(EarningsReleaseModel)
```

However, I get this error:

> sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: earningsreleasemodel

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
EarningsReleaseModel.create_table()
```

Is the correct syntax.